Implementing Raycasting in Gaussian Splatting Using Three.js
How can I place points at X, Y, Z coordinates in a 3D map using Three.js? I'm working with Gaussian Splatting representations, and right now, raycasting with a splat mesh doesn't work with Three.js's raycaster because raycasting against a splat mesh works differently (it returns intersections with splats, not Three.js meshes). How can I calculate intersections or place points correctly?

Could you show some attempt so far?
